# Row ID pass as a parameter in Magento Custom Module

Tags: magento

I have create a custom module in my project. 
From this module `Block->adminhtml->module->Grid.php page (Link :: /Block->adminhtml->module->Grid.php)`,

I want to pass parameter of row id `(Link :: Mage::getUrl('test.php', array('_query' => 'id=' . ???)))` .

How can i get row id as a parameter, i used `$this->getId();` but it doesn't work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Row Id is a nothing but your primary key id so If your primary field name is `customer_id` then method should be `$this->getCustomerId()`

In your case you have put space between `get` and `Id` so make you sure that your method should be `$this->getId();` and your primary key should be `id`

Comment: I have use $this->getId() in Grid.php page for primary key and print it, Result shows :: id_e19bf95eb40e761e145e3d924da4c44e. i am not getting my primary id.

In my question put space between get and Id was typing mistake.

@Sunny Rathod